# Focus indicator on a Microsoft droplist combo box not showing (sometimes)

Tags: c, winapi, mfc

I have a legacy application that uses Win32 (not MFC) to create graphical screens. One of the control types we use is a combo box with the droplist style (using the new Common Controls module). We have discovered a very strange thing about this control lately.

If I start the application with a mouse click, the focus indicator on the droplist does not show! This can be done using the Start->Run dialog (click OK after filling in the program to run). This can be done using a desktop shortcut (double-click). This can be done by clicking the Go button in Visual Studio 2010 to debug the program. Our user discovered this by using a small Delphi app that acts similar to Start->Run (fill in an entry field of a program to execute, and press a Launch button). If you click the Launch button, the focus indicator is missing.

If I start the application with a keypress, the focus indicator shows! Again, Start->Run dialog (but press Enter to activate the OK button). Desktop shortcut (single click to highlight the icon, then press Enter to activate it). F5 from within Visual Studio. Even the Delphi app - if you tab to the Launch button, and press Space or Enter, our application starts and shows the focus indicator on the drop list.

I have tried to create a small MFC application with just a drop list, and have started that application in all the ways described above. However, this small application always shows the focus indicator of the drop list, regardless of how I start it.

I have examined the styles of both drop lists (on my small application, as well as my actual application). They are slightly different, but changing the style of my small MFC app to match my desktop app doesn't change the behavior. Nor does changing my desktop app to match the style of the small MFC app change the behavior of my desktop app.

I modified my desktop application to require the user to press Enter after the main window is displayed, but before any graphical controls are shown. This causes the focus indicator to now show!

I have found that, when debugging my desktop app, if I set a breakpoint after the main window is shown, but before any controls are drawn, and then press F5 to continue, the focus indicator now shows. But if I click the Go button instead, the focus indicator does not show.

It seems like interacting with the keyboard somehow causes the focus indicator to show.

Note that a drop list combo box looks like a push button with a small down-arrow on the right hand side. The focus indicator is a dashed line near the inside border of the button.

I have struggled with this issue for two days now, with no indication that I am getting closer to an answer. So any insight into what may be causing this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Focus indicators are hidden by default unless the keyboard is used. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/10/05/792913.aspx. This isn't anything new - it was introduced in Windows 2000.

Comment: Can you reference an image so we are clear what you mean by 'focus indicator'?

Comment: I'm new to this group (though I've been lurking for a while). So I don't know how to reference an image. However, if you have iTunes installed on your PC, you can click Edit->Options. The first screen (General) has a couple of the drop lists. "List Size:", "Playlist Icon Size:", "When you insert a CD:" are three examples. If you tab to those fields, you will see the focus indicator. (Or if you can tell me how to reference an image, I will do that here.)

Comment: Jonathon - the blog post seems to refer to keyboard shortcut indicators, not focus indicators. But perhaps I am missing something.

Again, with iTunes and the Options dialog, you can click one of the drop lists (and select the same value). The focus indicator will now be on that drop list, and I haven't used the keyboard. All this to say that I'm not sure you understood my problem. Probably my fault for being overly verbose.

Comment: @RandyZack: Look at the heading of the blog post. Same theory, same rules apply.

Comment: @JonathonPotter - thanks for pointing that out. I missed it the first time. Sadly, with my desktop application, even tabbing between the different controls (and thus using the keyboard), the focus indicator does not appear if I started the application with the mouse.

The main issue for me is that the application works differently depending on how I start it - clicking vs typing.

Comment: @JonathonPotter - you are right. Changing that Control Panel setting causes the focus indicator to show regardless of how the application is started. I will type a full answer with my findings now.

Answer (score 1):

The first comment to the question provided a partial answer. Changing the Control Panel setting for keyboard accelerators also causes the focus indicator to show, regardless of how the application is started. However, I believe this is only a partial answer.

When the CP setting is off, keyboard accelerators are supposed to show once you have pressed the Alt key. My understand, based on the blog post that Jonathon Potter linked to, is that focus indicators should show up once the keyboard is used. Entering text into an entry field probably doesn't count as "using the keyboard", but I would expect tabbing between controls to count as such.

Also, if the CP setting is off, the behavior of my application is different, depending on whether I start the application with a mouse click or a key press.

In summary, I find the behavior inconsistent. Perhaps it is correct. I find it hard to say.